# How do I send the order of multiple drag and drop or browsed files in FilePond?

Tags: filepond

I have set up FilePond and it is working well but my next task is to preserve the order that files are added to FilePond.

I'm allowing multiple files to be added and have auto upload enabled but due to file size, transfer time and FilePond's asynchronous uploads it isn't possible to assume on the server side that the first to finish transfer was the first in the list.

I can see from the documentation that it's possible to get/remove files via their index so is it possible to use the file metadata plugin to send that index with each file uploaded.

Comment: Maybe you can use `onaddfile` to add the index to the file metadata. FilePond uploads the file metadata along with each file object so that should help sync things up.

Comment: Thanks @Rik I had been thinking of trying to get an index from FilePond, the main issue with this is that the index values aren't numeric or sequential. Using the onaddfile method I have tried creating a global counter variable and that seems to work quite well.  I'll paste my code below for anybody else that finds this question.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @Rik's comment I have created the following code snippet which works well.

```
let filecount = 0;

pond.on('addfile', (file) => {
    filecount += 1;
    file.setMetadata("filecount", filecount);
    ... Other metadata removed for brevity ... 
});
```